# SetState from Child Component fails on React Native

Tags: javascript, facebook, reactjs, react-native

I have a Child component which triggers a function in the Parent component. Although the function is triggered, the setState method seems to throw the following error.

> Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0): undefined is not an
>   object (evaluating '_this12.setState')

Child Component:

```
return (
    <View style={styles.buttonWrapper}>
        <View style={styles.socialMediaButtonWrapper}>
            <TouchableHighlight style={styles.socialMediaButtonBackFill} onPress={() => {
                this.props.onFacebookAuthenticationPressed()
            }}>
                <View style={[styles.socialMediaButtonFill, {backgroundColor: '#5158bb'}]}>
                    <FontAwesome style={styles.socialMediaButtonTextIconFill} name="facebook" size={20}/>
                </View>
            </TouchableHighlight>
        </View>
    </View>
);
```

Parent Component (Child Including Code):

```
<FacebookLoginComponent
    facebookAccessToken={this.state.facebookAccessToken}
    onFacebookAuthenticationPressed = {this.onFacebookAuthenticationPressed}
/>
```

Function:

```
onFacebookAuthenticationPressed: function () {
    LoginManager.logInWithReadPermissions(['public_profile', 'email']).then(function (result) {
        if (result.isCancelled) {
            console.log("Login Cancelled");
        } else {
            console.log("Login Successful");
            AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken().then(
                (data) => {
                    let accessToken = data.accessToken;
                    console.log(accessToken);
                    this.setState({
                        facebookAccessToken: accessToken
                    })
                })
        }
    }, function (error) {
        console.log("some error occurred!!");
    }).done(() => {
        this.markAsComplete();
    })
},
```

I'm using [react-native-fbsdk](https://github.com/facebook/react-native-fbsdk) library for Authentication. The token gets printed from the `console.log`, but the `setState()` fails.

Why is this? What's the workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Small fix for the child component (not neccessary, but better):

```
return (
    <View style={styles.buttonWrapper}>
        <View style={styles.socialMediaButtonWrapper}>
            <TouchableHighlight style={styles.socialMediaButtonBackFill} onPress={this.props.onFacebookAuthenticationPressed}>
                <View style={[styles.socialMediaButtonFill, {backgroundColor: '#5158bb'}]}>
                    <FontAwesome style={styles.socialMediaButtonTextIconFill} name="facebook" size={20}/>
                </View>
            </TouchableHighlight>
        </View>
    </View>
);
```

constructor of parent component:

```
this.onFacebookAuthenticationPressed = this.onFacebookAuthenticationPressed.bind(this);
```

I would not recommend to use bind in the render function. You should really use ES6 though, react native comes with support for that already. Class properties instead of bind:

```
onFacebookAuthenticationPressed = () => {
    LoginManager.logInWithReadPermissions(['public_profile', 'email']).then((result) => {
        ...
    }, function (error) {
        console.log("some error occurred!!");
    }).done(() => {
        this.markAsComplete();
    })
};
```

...or with ES5:

```
onFacebookAuthenticationPressed: function() {
    LoginManager.logInWithReadPermissions(['public_profile', 'email']).then(function (result) {
        ...
    }.bind(this), function (error) {
        console.log("some error occurred!!");
    }).done(function() {
        this.markAsComplete();
    }.bind(this));
};
```

Comment: Thanks. But at this moment and as of the stage of the project, moving to ES6 is a drastic change. Is there no way to fix this without moving away from ES5?

Comment: sure, use the bind function, but NOT in the render function. but you really should not use ES5 anymore, moving to ES6 is really easy and should work  without any changes in react native. you don´t need to move the whole project, you can even only use arrow functions and classes, for example.

Comment: i have updated the answer, check out the changes. you should actually be able to avoid this.onFacebookAuthenticationPressed.bind(this) that way, as react auto-binds the function anyway. mind the bind calls in onFacebookAuthenticationPressed though.

Comment: Thank you. This was descriptive. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

```
onFacebookAuthenticationPressed: function () {
    LoginManager.logInWithReadPermissions(['public_profile', 'email']).then((result) => {
        if (result.isCancelled) {
            console.log("Login Cancelled");
        } else {
            console.log("Login Successful");
            AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken().then(
                (data) => {
                    let accessToken = data.accessToken;
                    console.log(accessToken);
                    this.setState({
                        facebookAccessToken: accessToken
                    })
                })
        }
    }, function (error) {
        console.log("some error occurred!!");
    }).done(() => {
        this.markAsComplete();
    })
},
```

Notice the `result =>` here, which will pass this to your callback

Answer (score 0):

add bind(this) to the function ....

```js
<FacebookLoginComponent
    facebookAccessToken={this.state.facebookAccessToken}
    onFacebookAuthenticationPressed = {this.onFacebookAuthenticationPressed.bind(this)}// solution
/>
```

Comment: Doesn't work. Also gives the following warning "Warning: bind(): You are binding a component method to the component. React does this for you automatically in a high-performance way, so you can safely remove this call."

Comment: onFacebookAuthenticationPressed=  ()=> {} try to use arrow function

Comment: Can you elaborate please?

Comment: are you using es6 class syntax ? ..if yes then When you extend React.Component with ES2015 class syntax you need to bind your action handlers to a context of your class.otherwise it not be able to detect ' this ' .
or use arrow function to bind handlers .

Comment: Nope, this is ES5.

Comment: you are using es5 syntax in declaring function ....change that to es6 arrow function declaration.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159565/discussion-between-nimila-hiranya-and-rajat-gupta).

Comment: @NimilaHiranya The function would not be triggered if it was a problem with `bind`. The problem is that `accessToken` or `state` is somehow undefined.

Comment: no function will be triggered but all the things you try to access in that function with this  keyword will be undefined